# C# Reading from Comma Separated Text File to Windows Form

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, csv

I've created a windows form that takes user input and writes it to a text file in a comma separated manner and appends each new line.  I want to be able to read all the data from that file and display it to the user on another windows form in either a rich text box or label.

The code below is what I have to read in the data to a specific location on my machine.  I'm not sure if I first need to read the data into an array and then send that to a label or text box.

```
using (StreamWriter InputFile = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\person\Desktop\C#\New Text Document.txt"))
        {
            InputFile.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + "," + textBox4.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
```

I know there are many other posts like this, but I can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for

Comment: What happens if the user enters a comma in a text box?

Comment: @Enigmativity Don't even get me started....

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to read all lines in  an array  and using a code like the following

```
var lines =File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\person\Desktop\C#\New Text Document.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var col = line.Split(',');
                textBox1.Text = col[0]; 
                   textBox2.Text = col[1];
                textBox3.Text = col[2];
                textBox4.Text = col[3]; 
            }
```

Comment: When I use this example, I just get the last line read back....not everything in the file

Comment: Of course you need to insert the data in different textboxes at each loop!

Comment: @Justin - That's because that's how this code works. Your sample code shows you are only writing out one line, so this code effectively just gets the last line.

Comment: I'm actually using a label, not a text box but I do realize that this is probably not the best way to to about this.  How do I list everything in a text file at once?

Comment: Use a grid @Justin

Answer (score 1):

No, you could use `File.ReadLines`, which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
int i = 1;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
    string[] columns = line.Split(',');
    for (int c = 0; c < columns.Length; c++) {
        ((TextBox)Controls["textBox" + i++]).Text = columns[c];
    }
}
```

I assume that you have textboxes names `textBox1` to `textBox4` for the first line, `textBox5` to `textBox8` for the second line, and so on. But it would probably be better to use a grid.

Consider also using the `TextFieldParser` in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`. It does all the CSV processing for you. You will have to add a reference to the`Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`.

Note: the stuff in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll is just a .NET library like any other and works as well in C# as in VB.